# Finite-dimensionality of Ext¹ of simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology

For simplicity let $\Bbbk$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and let $A$ be a finitely generated unital associative $\Bbbk$-algebra.

Is it true that for any two simple $A$-modules $S_1, S_2$, we have that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A (S_1, S_2)$ is finite-dimensional?

If not, what would be a simple counterexample, and what sort of conditions do we need to ensure this?

(As far as I understand, the Weyl algebra $\Bbbk \langle x, y \rangle / (xy - yx - 1)$ has only infinite-dimensional simple modules, but their first extension groups are still finite-dimensional.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your claim about the Weyl algebra is only true for simple *holonomic* modules. It turns out that there’s a simple non-holonomic module $M$ over the 2nd Weyl algebra $A=A_2(\Bbb C)$ for which $\operatorname{Ext}_A^1(M,M)$ is infinite dimensional. This is Corollary 1.3 of “Non-holonomic modules over Weyl algebras and enveloping algebras” by Stafford.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm very happy that you have found a reasonable counterexample to my question! For the "first" Weyl algebra, the one in my question, it appears to be true (see [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869373900264), last line of the first page).

Answer (score 3):

It's true if $A$ is commutative. We can compute $\text{Ext}^1(S_1, S_2)$ using the first three terms of a free resolution of $S_1$; since $S_1$ is simple it's cyclic so the first term of this resolution is $A$ and the second term of this resolution is any finite set of generators of the kernel of $A \to S_1$, which is finitely generated because $A$ is Noetherian; Noetherianness also implies that we can take the third term (and in fact every term) to be finite free. So we get a levelwise finite free resolution

$$\cdots \to A^n \to A^m \to A \to S_1 \to 0$$

which computes $\text{Ext}^1(S_1, S_2)$ as a subquotient of $\text{Hom}(A^m, S_2) \cong S_2^m$; by the Nullstellensatz $\dim_k S_2$ is finite so $\dim_k \text{Ext}^1(S_1, S_2)$ must also be finite. More generally $\dim_k \text{Ext}^n(S_1, S_2)$ is finite.

If $A$ is noncommutative $\dim_k S_2$ may be infinite and the kernel of $A \to S_1$ may be infinitely generated (if $A$ is not Noetherian) so this argument fails in two places.

Comment: This is a nice way to see this! Geometrically, I think you can think of it as follows: simple modules $S_1$ and $S_2$ correspond to closed points $p_1$ and $p_2$ of $X = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ of the simple modules to $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ of the corresponding skyscraper sheaves $\mathcal O_{p_1}$ and $\mathcal O_{p_2}$. Then we should have $\dim \operatorname{Ext}^1 (\mathcal O_{p_1}, \mathcal O_{p_2}) = \dim X$ if $p_1 = p_2$ and zero otherwise, where the nonzero Ext corresponds to "moving the point". But this no longer makes sense in the noncommutative world.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: do you have a reference for that? I think I believe something like that ought to be true if $p_1 = p_2$ is smooth (and maybe we also need the residue field to be $k$) but I'm not convinced it holds in general.

Comment: I think $A = k[x]/x^2$ should be an explicit counterexample.

Comment: I think you're right and my argument only works for smooth points.